# material-ui textField color

Tags: material-ui

I'm using MUI 4.1.2
How is the textField color of the underline controlled when it's not active and when it's hovered?
I have changed the palette - text - primary, which controlled the underline when it's hovered, but I would like to do this with more specificity.

I've tried other solutions with overrides/MuiInput/underline/backgroundColor etc, which have not worked.

```
palette: {
  overrides {
    MuiInput: {
      underline: {
        '&:hover:before': {
          backgroundColor: "#fff"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overwrite underline styles by passing classes to `Input` component (which is a child of `TextField`). It is a bit hacky, but well, it works.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  underline: {
    // normal style
    "&::before": {
      borderBottom: "4px solid green"
    },
    // hover style
    "&:hover:not(.Mui-disabled):before": {
      borderBottom: "4px solid blue"
    },
    // focus style
    "&::after": {
      borderBottom: "4px solid red"
    }
  }
});

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <TextField InputProps={{ className: classes.underline }} label="example" />
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Here is live example:

[image: Edit upbeat-smoke-nqxws]

Comment: How do I do this in a class based component? I set it up using the "styled components API":
```
const MyTextField = styled(TextField)({
  underline: {
    "&::before": {
      borderBottom: "4px solid green"
    }
  }
)};
```

This didn't work...

Comment: @yodude you can make your own custom `TextField` component (with styles) and use it anywhere [live example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/magical-star-w51or)